# Oracle: Can IMP/EXP go to stdin/stdout?

Tags: oracle

I'm scripting some data transfer routines and incorporating `exp` and `imp` into the workflow.  Both of these have a `FILE=` parameter to specify the data file.

Is there a way to specify stdin and stdout?  I would love to do something like this:

```
exp ... | ssh foo imp ...
```

Right now I'm halfway tempted to work around this with mkfifo, but that seems a bit on the clunky side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite stdout/stdin but it is possible to export to and import from unix pipes.  Could this technique fit into your workflow? [Find out more.](http://mramkumar.blogspot.com/2008/06/export-and-import-using-unix-pipe-and.html)

Incidentally, Oracle's Data Pump does not work with unix pipes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use node files (man mknod) as a buffer file instead of a pipe (|).

Example:
On the destination host (dhost) were the dump should be created, execute:

```
ssh shost "cat /ORACLE_BACKUP_PATH/NAME_OF_THE_NODE_FILE" > FILE_NAME_ON_THE_DESTINATION_HOST
```

On the source host (shost) from were the backup should be created, execute:

```
expdp system/..... full=y directory=ORACLE_BACKUP_PATH DUMPFILE=NAME_OF_THE_NODE_FILE
```

Good Luck,
Mark